# mostrar dados da tabela entre duas datas escolhidas (as datas estão em varchar)

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM minhaTabela WHERE status=2
AND nomePessoa='Jose Silva' AND STR_TO_DATE(data_enviado, '%d/%m/%Y')
BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01/05/2015', '%d/%m/%Y')
AND STR_TO_DATE('31/06/2015', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

há algum modo de fazer um if/else?
tenho outras tabelas que a data não seguem esse padrão de **dia/mes/ano** (essa já está tratada ali emcima). algumas tabelas, a coluna `data_enviado`, está como  **ano-mes-dia**, algumas outras como **ano/mes/dia**, outras como **dia-mes-ano**; eu poderia fazer o tratamento no meu código php verificando o nome das tabelas, mas se existir uma forma mais fácil de fazer isso pelo sql...

Comment: O ideal era criar uma nova coluna do tipo `date` com os valores que vc já tem no banco de dados, assim acaba essa confusão.

Answer (score 0):

**Jerry**, tente:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
     minhaTabela
WHERE 
      status=2 AND 
      nomePessoa='Jose Silva' AND 
      DATE_FORMAT(str_to_date(data_enviado, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
      BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(str_to_date('01/05/2015', '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') AND
      DATE_FORMAT(str_to_date('31/06/2015', '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d');
```